# Regular expression in R for capturing names and paragraphs

Tags: r, regex

Can anyone tell me how to use Regular Expression in R to extract the two paragraphs of parliamentary speeches by Ms Anthea Ong, but exclude the one by Mr Chan Chun Sing?

```
txt <- "Ms Anthea Ong (Nominated Member): Thank you, Sir. I thank the Minister for that comprehensive response. I appreciate the Minister's assurance because, as the largest employer and given that one in seven Singaporeans has a mental health condition in their life time, we would not want to turn Singaporeans away who want to serve in the Public Service.

I just want to read this from someone who wrote to me: \"I tried to register as a relief teacher with MOE but was rejected just because I have a history of depression.\" Now, I understand, obviously, it is very textured. But I just want to ask the Minister, how are we ensuring that all Ministries and agencies will adhere to the TAFEP guideline. In addition, can the Minister also share if the Government allows for medical claims for psychiatric treatment and if mental health leave is given for Government employees. If not, are there plans to do so?

Mr Chan Chun Sing: Mr Deputy Speaker, I cannot comment on the specific case without further details. If Ms Anthea Ong has the specific details, we welcome her to provide MOE or the Public Service Division with the details and we can follow up on that."
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO! It would be better if you edited your question to follow our community's guidelines. Have a look at this link for advice on [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank so much for reminding me about the community's guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I formatted the example in your question a little bit to be valid `R` code. Taking this object, you can extract the text starting with `Ms Anthea Ong (Nominated Member):` up until `Mr Chan Chun Sing:`:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(gsub("\n", "", txt), "Ms Anthea Ong \\(Nominated Member\\):.*(?=Mr Chan Chun Sing:)")
#> [1] "Ms Anthea Ong (Nominated Member): Thank you, Sir. I thank the Minister for that comprehensive response. I appreciate the Minister's assurance because, as the largest employer and given that one in seven Singaporeans has a mental health condition in their life time, we would not want to turn Singaporeans away who want to serve in the Public Service.I just want to read this from someone who wrote to me: \"I tried to register as a relief teacher with MOE but was rejected just because I have a history of depression.\" Now, I understand, obviously, it is very textured. But I just want to ask the Minister, how are we ensuring that all Ministries and agencies will adhere to the TAFEP guideline. In addition, can the Minister also share if the Government allows for medical claims for psychiatric treatment and if mental health leave is given for Government employees. If not, are there plans to do so?"
```

This will only work if your vector is this one string though. If you use, for example, `readLines`, your string will be split into lines (above I simply remove linebreaks with `gsub("\n", "", txt)`). In this case you could do the following:

```
lines <- readLines(textConnection(txt)) # simulate readLines on a string

# grep returns position in vector, which can be used to subset it
lines[grep("^Ms Anthea Ong \\(Nominated Member\\):", lines):(grep("^Mr Chan Chun Sing:", lines)) - 1]
#> [1] "Ms Anthea Ong (Nominated Member): Thank you, Sir. I thank the Minister for that comprehensive response. I appreciate the Minister's assurance because, as the largest employer and given that one in seven Singaporeans has a mental health condition in their life time, we would not want to turn Singaporeans away who want to serve in the Public Service."                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#> [2] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#> [3] "I just want to read this from someone who wrote to me: \"I tried to register as a relief teacher with MOE but was rejected just because I have a history of depression.\" Now, I understand, obviously, it is very textured. But I just want to ask the Minister, how are we ensuring that all Ministries and agencies will adhere to the TAFEP guideline. In addition, can the Minister also share if the Government allows for medical claims for psychiatric treatment and if mental health leave is given for Government employees. If not, are there plans to do so?"
#> [4] ""
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed explanation!